# IPFS cluster raft error

Tags: ipfs, raft

when i run ipfs-cluster on docker, it didn't work.

I used docker-compose.

above is the docker-compose file that when I execute it.

**docker-compose file**

```
version: '2'
services:
  peer-1:
    image: ipfs/ipfs-cluster:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 4001:4001
      - 5001:5001
    volumes:
      - ./cluster/peer1/config:/data/ipfs-cluster
```

**LOGS**

```
peer-1_1  | Changing user to ipfs
peer-1_1  | ipfs-cluster-service version 0.5.0
peer-1_1  | Found IPFS cluster configuration at /data/ipfs-cluster
peer-1_1  | 20:47:24.349  INFO    service: Initializing. For verbose output run with "-l debug". Please wait... daemon.go:43
peer-1_1  | 20:47:24.410  INFO    cluster: IPFS Cluster v0.5.0-753322cd listening on:
peer-1_1  |         /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/9096/ipfs/QmNh9f4b1AMxTMKUGoQLv7JAuVD4f5RHuaQ7KUAzkKkybE
peer-1_1  |         /ip4/172.22.0.2/tcp/9096/ipfs/QmNh9f4b1AMxTMKUGoQLv7JAuVD4f5RHuaQ7KUAzkKkybE
peer-1_1  | 
peer-1_1  |  cluster.go:103
peer-1_1  | 20:47:24.414  INFO  consensus: existing Raft state found! raft.InitPeerset will be ignored raft.go:203
peer-1_1  | 20:47:24.415  INFO    restapi: REST API (HTTP): /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/9094 restapi.go:403
peer-1_1  | 20:47:24.426  INFO    restapi: REST API (libp2p-http): ENABLED. Listening on:
peer-1_1  |         /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/9096/ipfs/QmNh9f4b1AMxTMKUGoQLv7JAuVD4f5RHuaQ7KUAzkKkybE
peer-1_1  |         /ip4/172.22.0.2/tcp/9096/ipfs/QmNh9f4b1AMxTMKUGoQLv7JAuVD4f5RHuaQ7KUAzkKkybE
peer-1_1  | 
peer-1_1  |  restapi.go:420
peer-1_1  | 20:47:24.427  INFO   ipfshttp: IPFS Proxy: /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/9095 -> /ip4/192.168.58.144/tcp/5001 ipfshttp.go:209
peer-1_1  | 20:47:25.728 ERROR       raft: NOTICE: Some RAFT log messages repeat and will only be logged once logging.go:105
peer-1_1  | 20:47:25.729 ERROR       raft: Failed to make RequestVote RPC to {Voter QmZfjY68zhtEDYhWgiqz2jfFBe2JPn5fTiXFtZC8mZvGS7 QmZfjY68zhtEDYhWgiqz2jfFBe2JPn5fTiXFtZC8mZvGS7}: dial attempt failed: failed to dial <peer.ID ZfjY68> (default failure) logging.go:105
peer-1_1  | 20:47:27.722 ERROR       raft: Failed to make RequestVote RPC to {Voter QmZfjY68zhtEDYhWgiqz2jfFBe2JPn5fTiXFtZC8mZvGS7 QmZfjY68zhtEDYhWgiqz2jfFBe2JPn5fTiXFtZC8mZvGS7}: dial backoff logging.go:105
peer-1_1  | 20:47:44.428 ERROR    cluster: ***** ipfs-cluster consensus start timed out (tips below) ***** cluster.go:363
peer-1_1  | 20:47:44.428 ERROR    cluster: 
peer-1_1  | **************************************************
peer-1_1  | This peer was not able to become part of the cluster.
peer-1_1  | This might be due to one or several causes:
peer-1_1  |   - Check the logs above this message for errors
peer-1_1  |   - Check that there is connectivity to the "peers" multiaddresses
peer-1_1  |   - Check that all cluster peers are using the same "secret"
peer-1_1  |   - Check that this peer is reachable on its "listen_multiaddress" by all peers
peer-1_1  |   - Check that the current cluster is healthy (has a leader). Otherwise make
peer-1_1  |     sure to start enough peers so that a leader election can happen.
peer-1_1  |   - Check that the peer(s) you are trying to connect to is running the
peer-1_1  |     same version of IPFS-cluster.
peer-1_1  | **************************************************
peer-1_1  |  cluster.go:364
peer-1_1  | 20:47:44.428  INFO    cluster: shutting down Cluster cluster.go:431
peer-1_1  | 20:47:44.428  INFO  consensus: stopping Consensus component consensus.go:176
peer-1_1  | 20:47:49.502 WARNI  consensus: timed out waiting for state updates before shutdown. Snapshotting may fail raft.go:414
peer-1_1  | 20:47:49.502 ERROR       raft: Failed to take snapshot: nothing new to snapshot logging.go:105
peer-1_1  | 20:47:49.502  INFO    monitor: stopping Monitor pubsubmon.go:154
peer-1_1  | 20:47:49.502  INFO    restapi: stopping Cluster API restapi.go:438
peer-1_1  | 20:47:49.502  INFO   ipfshttp: stopping IPFS Proxy ipfshttp.go:536
peer-1_1  | 20:47:49.502  INFO pintracker: stopping MapPinTracker maptracker.go:119
```

ipfspeerconfig_    peer-1_1 exited with code 0

When i see the logs, Error is occurred by raft. what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of cluster is v0.10.1, you may need to pull the image directly before running the docket compose file again.